# What is the name of a symetric Toeplitz matrix with the first row forming a geometric serie?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, toeplitz-matrices

The title says all. I can't find the name of such a matrix, I'm almost sure it has one...
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&a&a^2&..&..&..&a^{n-1}\\a&1&a&a^2&..&..&a^{n-2}\\a^2&a&1&a&a^2&..&a^{n-3}\\..&&&..&&&..\\..&&&&..&&..\\..&&&&&..&..\\a^{n-1}&..&..&..&a^2&a&1\end{bmatrix}
$$